# Laravel : How to insert checkbox values with submit button?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

```
<form action="button" method="POST">`
<input type="checkbox" name="feature1"  id="clickme" ><b>Select<b/>`
</form> 

<script src="<?php echo url(); ?>/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#clickme').click(function()
{ 
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
        $(this).val('1');
        alert('value is set 1');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).val('0');
        alert('value is set 0');
    }
});    

});
```

Comment: Please do effort to make code in format to view properly.

Comment: Please do not post code to comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#clickme').click(function()
{ 
    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
var checkedVal='';
//insert.php write insert code in PHP
     checkedVal=$(this).val('1');
  $.ajax({url: "insert.php", 
  data:{cheecked_val:checkedVal},
  success: function(result){
        alert('Data Transferred successfully');
    }});
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).val('0');
        alert('value is set 0');
    }
});    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="clickme" />  Check Hear
```

Comment: hai i gave assign the values but only one checkbox was selected another boxes are not select what can i do .......

Comment: If you want to select all checkboxes  you can assign class for all checkboxes and use $.each method.you will get perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do that.  Just add your checkbox and set the value.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="feature1" value="1"><b>Select<b/>
```

The way this works is this checkbox's value will only be passed if it's been checked so there is no need to toggle the value between 1 and 0.  All you need to do is check if the input is there.

```
if (request()->has('feature1')) {
    // Code if feature1 has been checked
}
```